# Memory error when I am trying to use Gridsearchcv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, memory-leaks, gridsearchcv

I am working on a customized estimator that should be passed in gridsearchcv function in sklearn. I have created the estimator now but run into a memory error. In the following code, you will see some constants  like 'KxRange[0]' or arrays like retain_rate. They are just pre-defined with some random values in them.
Here is my code:

```
# sklearn grid search
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# import the base estimator
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
# define my own estimator
class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator,RegressorMixin):
    # define constructor
    #  possible tau: int/float
    #  other parameters: array of int/floats, length 9
    def __init__(self, tau=0, \
                       K1=K1Range[0], K2=K2Range[0], K3=K3Range[0], K4=K4Range[0], K5=K5Range[0], K6=K6Range[0], K7=K7Range[0], K8=K8Range[0], K9=K9Range[0], \
                       S1=0, S2=0, S3=0, S4=0, S5=0, S6=0, S7=0, S8=0, S9=0, \
                       alpha1=1, alpha2=1, alpha3=1, alpha4=1, alpha5=1, alpha6=1, alpha7=1, alpha8=1, alpha9=1, \
                       beta1=1, beta2=1, beta3=1, beta4=1, beta5=1, beta6=1, beta7=1, beta8=1, beta9=1):
        # initialize parameters
        self.tau = tau
        self.K1 = K1
        self.K2 = K2
        self.K3 = K3
        self.K4 = K4
        self.K5 = K5
        self.K6 = K6
        self.K7 = K7
        self.K8 = K8
        self.K9 = K9
        self.S1 = S1
        self.S2 = S2
        self.S3 = S3
        self.S4 = S4
        self.S5 = S5
        self.S6 = S6
        self.S7 = S7
        self.S8 = S8
        self.S9 = S9
        self.alpha1 = alpha1
        self.alpha2 = alpha2
        self.alpha3 = alpha3
        self.alpha4 = alpha4
        self.alpha5 = alpha5
        self.alpha6 = alpha6
        self.alpha7 = alpha7
        self.alpha8 = alpha8
        self.alpha9 = alpha9
        self.beta1 = beta1
        self.beta2 = beta2
        self.beta3 = beta3
        self.beta4 = beta4
        self.beta5 = beta5
        self.beta6 = beta6
        self.beta7 = beta7
        self.beta8 = beta8
        self.beta9 = beta9
    # to fit the model
    def fit(self, X,y=None):
        # define the mu vector
        self.mu_ = np.ones((N))
        # define lag weights
        lag_weights = np.ones((max_lag))
        # define retain_rate
        retain_rate = np.array([alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, alpha4, alpha5, alpha6, alpha7, alpha8, alpha9])
        # define cum_effect, set to a random value
        cum_effect = 1
        # define cum_effects_hill
        cum_effects_hill = np.ones((N, num_media))
        # parameter transformation
        for nn in range(N):
            for m in range(num_media):
                for l in range(max_lag): 
                    lag_weights[l] = retain_rate[m]**l
                cum_effect = Adstock(X[nn][m], lag_weights)
            cum_effects_hill[nn][m] = Hill(cum_effect, ec[m], slope[m])
            self.mu_[nn] = tau + np.dot(cum_effects_hill[nn], beta_medias)
        return self
    # the predict function
    def predict(self, X, y=None):
        # try to get the mu_ argument. If it does not exist, we throw an error
        try:
            getattr(self, "mu_")
        except AttributeError:
            raise RuntimeError("You must train classifer before predicting data!")
        return self.mu_
    # the score function
    def score(self, X, y):
        # calculate the MSE
        return np.dot(y - self.predict(X), y - self.predict(X))/len(X)
```

The following is like the "main" function

```
# initiliaze estimator
t = MyEstimator()
# parameter grid
             # tau  
param_grid = {'tau': [100,200], \
             # K
              'K1': [K1Range[0], K1Range[1]], 'K2' : [K2Range[0], K2Range[1]], 'K3': [K3Range[0], K3Range[1]], 'K4' : [K4Range[0], K4Range[1]], 'K5' : [K5Range[0], K5Range[1]], 'K6' : [K6Range[0], K6Range[1]], 'K7' : [K7Range[0], K7Range[1]], 'K8': [K8Range[0], K8Range[1]], 'K9': [K9Range[0], K9Range[1]], \
             # S
              'S1': [1, 100], 'S2': [1, 100], 'S3': [1, 100], 'S4': [1, 100], 'S5': [1, 100], 'S6': [1, 100], 'S7': [1, 100], 'S8': [1, 100], 'S9': [1, 100], \
             # alpha
              'alpha1': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha2': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha3': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha4': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha5': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha6': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha7': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha8': [0.1, 0.5], 'alpha9': [0.1, 0.5], \
             # beta
              'beta1': [100,200], 'beta2': [100,200], 'beta3': [100,200], 'beta4': [100,200], 'beta5': [100,200], 'beta6': [100,200], 'beta7': [100,200], 'beta8': [100,200], 'beta9': [100,200]}
#
clf = GridSearchCV(t, param_grid)
clf.fit(X_media, actual_sales)
#clf.predict(X_media)
```

This is error message:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-de0388db8453> in <module>
     14 #
     15 clf = GridSearchCV(t, param_grid)
---> 16 clf.fit(X_media, actual_sales)
     17 #clf.predict(X_media)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    734                 return results
    735 
--> 736             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    737 
    738         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1186     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1187         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1188         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1189 
   1190 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    698 
    699             def evaluate_candidates(candidate_params):
--> 700                 candidate_params = list(candidate_params)
    701                 n_candidates = len(candidate_params)
    702 

MemoryError:
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error? Or is there any problem with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The traceback shows that the grid search runs out of memory already at trying to generate the list of candidates, i.e. the grid.  You apparently have 37 parameters, each with two possible values, so the number of candidates is `2^(37)`, more than 137 billion.  You really probably don't want to try that many candidates anyway, so maybe a `RandomizedSearchCV` is more appropriate?

Comment: Thank you Ben. I am trying to do `RandomizedSearchCV` now